# c# how to get one value from substring

Tags: c#, substring

How to solve this?

**What i want to change this :**

C:\files\team\business\dev\Source\systems\extension\destination\1.0.1.1\

**to new value:**

value = "1.0.11";

Comment: Well, read documentation on .Net string class. Very powerful. Then, try to have clear requirements and, well, why not actually coding something?

Comment: @Kek, why reading the documentation of the `string` class? I'd rather say reading the documentation of the `DirectoryInfo` class as shown in my answer.

Comment: Depending on requirement actually... you guessed @user1358072 wanted to extract directories... Congratulations, I could not manage to deduce it : I have this, I want that... and, well, waht is that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just get the [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx) of the corresponding [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx):

```
string path = @"C:\files\team\business\dev\Source\systems\extension\destination\1.0.1.1\";
string version = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;
```

Comment: note that this requires read permission on the specified directory, shouldn't be a problem in most cases.

Comment: Will this really lead to disk operations, or is it simply doing string manipulation? Clearly with stuff like `new DirectoryInfo(path).Exists` it will have to do an I/O operation. Of course the philosophy of using the the utilities of the framework to handle file paths instead of ad-hoc string manipulation, is very reasonable.

Comment: Unless someone can guarantee that the above use of `DirectoryInfo` does not lead to permission checks or disk reads, I would go with a solution with the `Path` class, as in Eren Ersönmez's answer.

Comment: Yes, this will lead to I/O - permission checks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method:

```
var path = @"C:\files\team\business\dev\Source\systems\extension\destination\1.0.1.1\";
var value = Path.GetFileName(path.TrimEnd(new[]{'/','\\'}));
// OUTPUT: 1.0.1.1
```

This basically removes any last directory delimeters and then treats the last directory as a filename, so it returns the last directory.

---

Based on **@JeppeStigNielsen**'s comments below, here's a better, platform independent alternative.

```
var value = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
```

This will work if there is a file name present as well.

```
var value = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(".../1.0.1.1/somefile.etc"));
// returns 1.0.1.1
```

Comment: I tried `Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))`, and it seemed to work too.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen that's even better, because it would work even if there's a filename present.

Comment: In your version, one _could_ change `new[]{'/','\\'}` into `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar,Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`. Note that the `TrimEnd` method has `params` modifyer on its argument, so the array creation syntax is redundant.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen true also.

Answer (score 0):

[*Darin's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012081/447156) is great but as an alternative;

```
string s = @"C:\files\team\business\dev\Source\systems\extension\destination\1.0.1.1\";

string[] array = s.Split('\\');
Console.WriteLine(array[array.Length - 2]);
```

Output will be;

```
1.0.1.1
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/S0kGzh).

Comment: Why use `.Count` with Linq when you can check the length of `array`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yep, you are right. That's pointless. Updated.